# How to execute ruby script from Jenkins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins

I added this step in my Jenkins Job

**Execute Shell**

```
 FILE=copy_S3.rb
 cat > "$FILE" << EOF
 #!/usr/bin/env ruby
 libPath =  ENV["WORKSPACE"]+"/../lib/"
 puts libPath
 $LOAD_PATH.unshift( libPath ) 
 EOF

 ruby ./copy_S3.rb
```

I'm getting an error

```
./copy_S3.rb:5:in `<main>': undefined method `unshift'
```

Comment: I'm using a windows machine running cygwin

Comment: Examine _copy_S3.rb_ in the workspace after your job runs. Does it contain the expected content? It is likely that $LOAD_PATH is being replaced by the shell as the file is created. Why not check out your copy_S3 script from a source repository?